# I am using Selenium-webdriver and I need to select an element by its "text"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need dynamic `xpath` because the one I have is not finding an element.

```
 public void selectCheckBox(WebElement wrapper, String value) {
    scrollTo(wrapper);
    String xpath = ".//label[span/text()='" + value + "']//input[@type='checkbox']";
    try {
        WebElement checkboxButton = wrapper.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
        checkboxButton.click();
        waitPageBusy();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        // Checkbox not found.
        step("Missing checkbox: " + value, () -> {
            attachment("Available values", String.join("\n", getRadioValues(wrapper)));
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Missing checkbox: " + value, e);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide HTML example for this particular  element?

The label might look something like this:

```
 <label>
        <span>Text</span>
        <input type="checkbox">
 </label>
```

So the xpath selector will be `//label[span/text()='Text']/input[@type='checkbox']`.

This selector works in chrome dev tools. Maybe you have too much dashes before "input"?

Or the problem is in "wrapper" and it doesn't contain what you expect.

Another problem could be that the text in HTML includes some whitespaces, in which case you can try "contains" - `//label[contains(span/text(), 'Text')]/input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: Here's my HTML

<div class ="gw-InputGroup--header--label">
2015 DAIHATSU GRAN MAX 1.5 P/U D/S D/S (CA6876 788)
</div>

Comment: This HTML doesn't contain any <label>, <span> or <input> which you are searching for.
If you want to select this <div>, use `//div[contains(text(), '2015 DAIHATSU GRAN MAX')]`